# How to handle runtime exceptions in a chain of methods?

Tags: java, exception, runtime

I recently went through an interview process of a company where I was asked this question:

Lets say there are three methods :
           A(), B() and C();
the flow is as:

```
A(){
    B();
}

B(){
    C();
}

and 
C()
{
          // The code here may throw runtime exception.
}
```

Now, in our main method, we called method A() and an exception occurred in C().
So the questions was how to handle this situation ?
The first solution that came to my mind was that we can use throws keyword and inside A() method, we can apply try-catch block.

But the interviewer didnt look satisfied and it may be the case that i didnt give the answer which he expected.

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: Technical Interview Questions always HIT the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

Based in the business going on, you have 2 options.

1) Handle the situation on the spot, which means try catch and do necessary steps in method `C()`

or

2) Just re `throw` it to the caller until it reaches to the parent caller `A()`, so that it handles the situation.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is not to do anything to recover from the runtime exception just let the compiler throw the error ,I mean do not handle Rumtime exceptions at all , the reason is below

> Since Runtime exceptions/unchecked exceptions represent problems that are the result of a programming problem such as dividing by zero; trying to access an object through a null reference; and indexing exceptions,attempting to access an array element through an index that is too large or too small..etc..

[According to Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

> If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your requirement

1 approach :- You can declare the **Exception Type** with signature of every function.
eg.

```
A() throws ExceptionType
{
    B();
}


B() throws ExceptionType{
    C();
}

and 
C() throws ExceptionType
{
          // The code here may throw runtime exception.
}
```

2nd Approach :-

```
    try
    {
    a();
    }catch(ExceptionType){}
A(){
    B();
}

B(){
    C();
}

and 
C()
{
          // The code here may throw runtime exception.
}
```

3rd Approach :-
you can call each and every function within

```
try
{
//Function Calling
}catch(ExceptionType){//handeling code}
```